# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'darts'

Tags: python, installation, error-handling, anaconda, u8darts

I followed all the steps described in the Installation procedure of UNIT8, like creating on Python 3.7 ENV on Anaconda and executing *pip install u8darts[all]*.

But this error message keeps popping up on the console screen.

The Code is pretty basic so far:

```
from darts.models import NBEATSModel

model_PLDHorario = NBEATSModel(input_chunk_length = 48, output_chunk_length = 24)
```

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://github.com/unit8co/darts/issues/258